# Defining series before enumitem list starts

Tags: pdftex, enumerate, enumitem

I have the following code. How can we define `series = A` before the first `\begin{enumerate}`, so that all `\begin{enumerate}` would be uniform, that is, all equal to `\begin{enumerate}[resume = A]` ?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}[series=A]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}

\vbox{
\begin{enumerate}[resume=A]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}
}

\vbox{
\begin{enumerate}[resume=A]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set `enumerate` to use `resume`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\setlist[enumerate]{resume}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I don't know what `\vbox` was for, so I removed it.

However, it would be better to use a different name.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{globalenum}{enumerate}{1}
\setlist[globalenum]{label=\arabic*.,resume}

\begin{document}

\begin{globalenum}
\item this is an item.
\end{globalenum}

\begin{globalenum}
\item this is an item.
\end{globalenum}

\begin{globalenum}
\item this is an item.
\end{globalenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For the `\vbox` approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newcounter{outerenum}
\newenvironment{outerenum}
 {\par\addvspace{\topsep}\vbox\bgroup
  \begin{enumerate}[nosep]\setcounter{enumi}{\value{outerenum}}}
 {\end{enumerate}\egroup\addvspace{\topsep}\stepcounter{outerenum}}

\begin{document}

\begin{outerenum}
\item this is an item.
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Inner
  \item Inner
  \item Inner
\end{enumerate}
\end{outerenum}

\begin{outerenum}
\item this is an item.
\end{outerenum}

\begin{outerenum}
\item this is an item.
\end{outerenum}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, @egreg! I need `vbox` to prevent page breaks, but, unfortunately, your solution appears to be incompatible with `vbox`, as the resulting numbering of the list is wrong when using `vbox`.

Comment: @PaulS Then you're using the wrong tools. Is there always a single item in the `\vbox`?

Comment: Thanks, @egreg! Each `\vbox` has single outer item and multiple one-level nested items. Do you think there is a better solution than the `\vbox` one?

Comment: @PaulS Not for the `\vbox`, but for the whole thing. Yours is definitely an XY question. Please, open a new one, with more details. My guess is that you're preparing exercise sets, but that's not really relevant.

Comment: Thanks again, @egreg. I had already opened such a question, but got no answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/649369/items-of-a-randomly-enumerate-list-not-breaking-pages. This solution with `\ vbox` works fine, but, since the lists are generated by a computer program (that writes the latex code), it would simplify my computer program to be able to set the list as resumable before starting the list iteself.

Comment: @PaulS Sorry, but that question is too vague.

Comment: Thanks for the time you devoted to my question, @egreg. The solution with `series` works fine inside `\vbox` and I only have to instruct the program that generates the latex code to insert `series = A` in the first `\begin{enumerate}` -- I was just trying to find out whether a simple latex solution existed.

Comment: @PaulS I added a possible approach for the `\vbox`. Maybe you can adapt it to you real problem.

Comment: Your solution for the `vbox` works sublimely, @egreg! It also works great with `multicol`, which I really need to use with the lists! I cannot thank you enough for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can start the series before the enumerate:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\SetEnumitemKey{series=A}

\begin{enumerate}[resume=A]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}

\vbox{
\begin{enumerate}[resume=A]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}
}

\vbox{
\begin{enumerate}[resume=A]
\item this is an item.
\end{enumerate}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That is another great solution solution! Thanks a lot, @UlrikeFischer!